# Use a single page component.vue in a not laravel php page

Tags: php, html, vue.js

in the last months I made some great progress using vue, and just a couple of days ago a friend asked me if I can do a little plugin for his page, that is made in pure PHP. I made a vue.js component, call it test.vue . It is Single File Component with script and template all togheter. Now, I tested it on my local enviroment on an laravel App the I was developing, and it works fine. But I don't understand how I can add it to the php page of him. In my App, I got NPM running and recompiling all my jss and css, but now that I have this single file I kind of lost the direction.

How can I run the single file component in a out of laravel php page? In laravel I just register the component in my app.js, do the npm mix and then just add the component markup into a blade view and everything works..

Some help will be much appreciate

Comment: Just run `npm run build` and add the output scripts of /dist to your markup.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So in my app.js I got many script all beginning with: /* 01 */ /*02*/ etc etc 
the one that I think is the right one should be this:/* 82 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) { .. 

I should add it withing <script> tags in the footer?

Comment: You just include the app and vendor files via script tags in your head, those will include all the other chunks. Make sure to deploy the chunks as well though.

Comment: Ok. So, seen that I made the component, I should not have to any vendor file right? Just the app.js in a <script src... ?

Comment: You'll most likely need the vendor as well. If you're using vue cli you can also compile it into a web component if that fits your needs better: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann So, thank you very much for your help. It worked out just by referencing the app.js script in the footer. No vendor needed. If you put your comment in an answer I'll be glad to flag it as answered.